# unable to change default URL at "General Settings" page

Tags: pluggable

Okay I have the Default URL for the blog at "General settings" grayed out and unable to change the url of the blog anymore. The current value is "http://blog.financialcoachshow.com/blueocean/institutional"

[screenshot link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMplz.png)

I know this happens when you have custom defined for the site/blog url at the wp-config.php file , however I have the following defined in wp-config.php

```
define ('WPLANG', '');
define('WP_HOME','http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/company');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://www.blueoceanportfolios.com/company');
```

while I was hoping to have SiteUrl/blog url at "General Settings" blueoceanportolios.com/company  as defined above it is locked to http://blog.financialcoachshow.com/blueocean/institutional

What else could be causing be the possible reason for such conflicting value ?

Comment: check your function files. Try disabling plugins and mu-plugins if any are installed.

Answer (score 1):

In `functions.php` look for lines like

```
update_option('siteurl','http://blog.financialcoachshow.com/blueocean/institutional');
update_option('home','http://blog.financialcoachshow.com/blueocean/institutional');
```

Delete them!